# chmod operation not permitted in php file

Tags: php, email, file-permissions

I have been trying to change the permissions of the folder via php file and getting operation not permittted error.

Due to this I'm not able to attach the attachment for sending it via email using PHP.

The file uploaded to folder is by default getting lock symbol.

```
chmod('./uploads', 0777);
$target='./uploads/';
```

My folder permission are 777

Any solution for this...

Comment: The user that the PHP script is running at does not have permission to change this.  You need to set permissions on deployment.  This is by design and is a Linux/Unix thing, not a PHP thing.

Comment: Can you suggest any solution for this @AlexBarker